# How can I do to redirect if already logged in when user enter in /login?

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I am developing an application, but when I switch from page to another, I get redirected to login page, how can I change the redirection to another page if the user is already logged in because it redirects to log in automatically now.

---

## app.js

```
'use strict';

// declare modules
angular.module('testt', []);
angular.module('Homee', []);
angular.module('Contart' , []);
angular.module('Condidature' , []);

angular.module('BasicHttpAuthExample', [
    'testt',
    'Homee',
    'Contart',
    'Condidature',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
])

.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
        })

        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/contrat',{
            controller: 'ContartController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/contrat/views/contart.html'
        })
        .when('/candidatute',{
            controller: 'CondidatureController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/Candidature/views/candidature.html'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in
            if ($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: I think you need to check  $rootScope.globals and $rootScope.globals.currentUser, as I see, in your code, this is only one reason to redirect to /login

Comment: Any feedback adam?

Answer (score 2):

What about reversing your force login page redirect. This should give you the trick.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    // redirect to login page if not logged in
    if ($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }

    // redirect to home page if logged in
    if ($location.path() === '/login' && $rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $location.path('/home');
    }
});
```